# Using DynamoDB instead of Cassandra in cadence

Tags: uber-cadence

Is it possible to configure dynamoDB instead of Cassandra. If possible can please share any instructions on it. I couldn't find any in https://github.com/uber/cadence/blob/master/docker/README.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible as DynanamoDB is not fully compatible with Cassandra semantic as related to conditional batch operations.